# Help solve this Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $a +b +c =5$ and $ab +ac +bc=$5, what is the value of $a^2+b^2+c^2$?

Comment: $$(a+b+c)^2=?$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$(a+b+c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2(ab+ac+bc)$$

Answer (score 2):

$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)\Rightarrow a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)=25-10=15$